# Multiple key values in $_POST

Tags: php, html, post

I'm using Yii 2 currently to build a little quiz and I wanted to check my approach. My quiz is one question per page and I am using a session to get all the question IDs and answers. I should add, I have multiple quizzes so the quiz ids aren't necessarily incremental.

When the answer is posted back I need to capture the question ID and the option ID that was selected. These were in the format of

```
<input type="radio" name="6" value="12"> // 6 being the question and 12 the option_id
```

As I don't know what the next question is as I'm just incrementing `++` through an array.

If I change my code to be this

```
<input type="radio" name="question" value="6,12">
```

Is that a decent way to get the information as I will always know that the question is called question and I can explode the value or split it in some way, or should I use square brackets?

I wasn't sure how to do this in Yii 2. My current code is:

```
echo Html::radioList('question', NULL, [$q->question_id . ',' . $q->question_option_id => $q->option], ['class' =>'radioId']);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think using array syntax might be the best way to handle this. You can make `questions` an array and make the question ID the key and have the value be the `value` attribute in your HTML.

I think the code example below will demonstrate it best.

Your HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="question[6]" value="12">
```

Your PHP:

```
echo $_POST['question'][6]; // output: 12
```